# Deprecated/replaced methods, how do you target all versions?

Tags: android

Many times in Android , you see that a method is deprecated as of version 3.0 and a different method should be used.

How do you handle such things when programming your app if you are targeting most of the devices (say from Version 2.1). Do you code the same app multiple times each one for different version? and then create different profiles in Google Play for each APK? I find it this a bit excessive and does not make sense. Please let me know what is the correct way of handling such situations

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easiest approach would be to simply check what version your app is running on act accordingly. I.e.

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
   [code for HC and up]
} else {
   [code for older versions]
}
```

You can find all version codes [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html). Remember you need to build your app with `targetSdk` set to latest possible. This is however risky as you can easily use method not available on older platforms and your application would crash as compiler won't warn you. To mitigate this it usually helps to pay attention what are you using :) but also to wrap such "risky" code into library or utility class so you can be sure no other code of yours does that trickery by itself. It also helps to set API filter on documentation at http://d.android.com/ (these small up/down arrows on left titlebar, next to "Android APIs
) to **LOWEST** version you plan to support. In case it is something not used often, there's a chance you peek there catch the risk "visually"

There's also plugin for Eclipse that does such checks, but I do not use it myself and cannot remember its name at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestion. That defintly makes sense Accepted!. However, I have a question (excuse my stupidity), if I put the code snippet above in my code, and someone tries to run APK in older version, wouldn't the app crash at start up because there is code written for new versions whose apid does not exist yet in the old phone (even if the code is not excecuted)!?

Comment: No, you are safe, because we got `if()` (which does not depend on API) so the HC bytecode will not be executed if condition is not fulfilled (which means older API than HC). The trick here is you build with `targetSdk` set as high as possible, so the compiler knows what to do with your HC API code, but at the same time we got if() to ensure that code will not be executed on platform that does not know what to do with it (which would cause a crash - simply try and remove `if()`).

Comment: ohhhh I see that's why you said build with targetSdk as high as possible. Thanks a lot for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, no we don't create multiple apps.

A first solution would be check which android version this is and act accordingly:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

A second solution, based on the first one, would be to create an abstract class which defines basic functionality, and child classes with version-specific implementations.
The abstract class checks the version and creates the required child instance.
You just call the abstract method when you need it.
[Read more about it](http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/abstracting.html).

The first solution is good for small tasks. The second is better for more complex situations (e.g. using tabHost vs. the new tab navigation pattern).